# Use different force with UITouch in objective-c and 3dtouch

Tags: objective-c, 3dtouch

I'm trying include a force component in my objective c code as it should now be possible since ios9. 
my code contains the following 2 methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the touchesEnded method I'm trying to get the force of the touch event with the following lines of code:

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGFloat force = touch.force;
    CGFloat percentage = force/touch.maximumPossibleForce;
    NSLog(@"Printing force : %f", force);
    NSLog(@"Printing percentage: %f", percentage);
    NSLog(@"Printing maximum possible force: %f",    touch.maximumPossibleForce);
    break;
}
```

I'm trying to run my code on an iphone 6s and I get extremely weird and contradicting values, e.g. 
    force : 2.650000 
and 
    force : 0.066667
even though I think I'm pressing the buttons almost with equal force.

i do not want to implement peek and pop but just let users control the app with different options in one button.

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself and as I guess more and more people will try to use 3d touch in their apps so i hope this solution helps:

The key is that I had to create a touchesMoved method and put my code there as follows:

```
   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGFloat maximumPossibleForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce;
CGFloat force = touch.force;
CGFloat normalizedForce = force/maximumPossibleForce;
NSLog(@"Normalized force : %f", normalizedForce);

if (normalizedForce > 0.75)
{
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    NSLog(@"Strong");
} else {

NSLog(@"Weak");
}
```

}

my code simply vibrates if buttons are touched with force and that's it.